# Javascript assignment has me stumped

Tags: javascript, html

what I need to do:
I need to build a program which will ask users to enter their grades for 
1)assignment1 - 25points
2)assignment2 - 25points
3)assignment3 - 25points
4)assighment4 - 25points
5)exam1 - 100 points
6)final exam - 100 points
7)final project - 100 points

total points for all of the assignments is thus 400 points

Users are not allowed to enter negative scores, and they are not allowed to enter scores which go above the limits of total points possible for the assignments. After all scores have been entered I am to display the grades as both a percentage and a letter grade.

What works so far:
The program will not accept negatives, or any grades which go above the set limits of points possible for the assignments. I could not get an "Enter valid score (0-max)" message to work so I scrapped that feature, instead the program will not move forward until an appropriate value is entered. Also I am able to display a percent. But once you look at the code, you will see that the program does not actually calculate the percent, it simply calculates the (sum/total)*100 later I do a document.writeln where I simply add a "%" symbol. I found it easier this way.

What I cant get to work:
I can't get the damn letter grade. I know that because I am setting the letter grades to fall within a specific range (such as 93.9%-90% is an A-) that I should use if statements so I did, but I am not sure if I did it right, also I set a variable called "letter" which I tried to give a value of A, A-, B+, B, B-, etc, etc depending on the range in which the student fell. I can not get this to work.

Here is my code, any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am having a little bit of a problem here.

I can get the program to sum all of the grades and divide by the total thus giving me a percentage and displaying it when I run the program. What I cant seem to get it to do is to display the letter grade.

I have the if statements, which so far, and a variable called letter which I tried to insert into the first document.writeln that we see in the code, but when ever I try to use this variable and run the program the screen goes white. There are no prompts to enter scores, nothing, it just goes white.

I was thinking it was a problem with the way I did the if statements, but I don't know.

here is my code, some help would be appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <Title>Final Grade Calculation</Title>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var assignment1;
            var assignment2;
            var assignment3;
            var assignment4;
            var exam1;
            var finalexam;
            var finalproject;
            // the above variables represent the assignments, exams, and project.
            // the following lines of code will ask the user to enter their scores. We    will also try
            // to make sure that the user is not entering negative numbers, or numbers above the max set of points possible for each
            //assignment. Eash assignment is worth 25 points
            //exams are 100
            //and the final project is 100 as well, the total points possible should then be no more than 400
            //before we begin to prompt the user to enter their scores we will also declare a few more variables
            var a1; //assignment 1
            var a2; //assignment 2
            var a3; //assignment 3
            var a4; //assignment 4
            var e1; //exam1
            var ef; //final exam
            var fp; //final project
            var g; //is going to be ((a1+a2+...fp)/tp)
            var tp = 400; //total possible points
            var letter;
            //the following loops ensure that the user can only enter scores that fall withing the acceptable range for each respective assignment
            //assignments have  a min of 0, and a max of 25
            //exam1 has a min of 0, and a max of 100
            //finalexam has a min of 0 and a max of 100
            //final project has a min of 0 and a max of 100
            //if there is no score entered into the prompt then the variable for the respective assignment is 0 by default.


            do
            {
                assignment1=window.prompt("Enter your score for assignment 1");
                a1=parseInt(assignment1);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (a1 < 0 || a1 > 25 )
            if (assignment1=null)
            a1=0


            do
            {
                assignment2=window.prompt("Enter your score for assignment 2");
                a2=parseInt(assignment2);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (a2 < 0 || a2 > 25 )
            if (assignment2=null)
            a2=0

            do
            {
                assignment3=window.prompt("Enter your score for assignment 3");
                a3=parseInt(assignment3);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (a3 < 0 || a3 > 25 )
            if (assignment1=null)
            a3=0

            do
            {
                assignment4=window.prompt("Enter your score for assignment 4");
                a4=parseInt(assignment4);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (a4 < 0 || a4 > 25 )
            if (assignment4=null)
            a4=0

            do
            {
                exam1=window.prompt("Enter your score for exam 1");
                e1=parseInt(exam1);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (e1 < 0 || e1 > 100 )
            if (exam1=null)
            e1=0

            do
            {
                finalexam=window.prompt("Enter your score for the final exam");
                ef=parseInt(finalexam);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (ef < 0 || ef > 100 )
            if (finalexam=null)
            ef=0

            do
            {
                finalproject=window.prompt("Enter your score for the final project");
                fp=parseInt(finalproject);
                //window.alert("Invalid Score entered");
            }
            while (fp < 0 || fp > 100 )
            if (finalproject=null)
            fp=0

            // g is the variable which will be representing the final grade.
            //is will give us a decimal as an answer
            g = ((a1+a2+a3+a4+e1+ef+fp)/tp)*100
            document.writeln("<h1>Your final score is " + g.toFixed(2) +"%</h>"); //we convert the decimal into a percentage, not really though
            //the percentage displayed is only superficial, to be honest I was getting frustrated trying to find a way to make real percents
            //the following if's will assign letter grades to a range of decimals.



            if (g>=94)
            {letter="A"}
            else if (g>=93.90 || g<=90.00)
            {letter="A-"}
            else if (g>=89.90 || g<=87.00)
            {letter="B+"}
            else if (g>=86.90 || g<=84.00)
            {letter="B"}
            else if (g>=83.90 || g<=80.00)
            {letter="B-"}
            else if (g>=79.90 || g<=77.00)
            {letter="C+"}
            else if (g>=76.90 || g<=74.00)
            {letter="C"}
            else if (g>=73.90 || g<=70.00)
            {letter="C-"}
            else if (g>=69.90 || g<=67.00)
            {letter="D+"}
            else if (g>=63.90 || g<=60.00)
            {letter="D-"}
            else
            {letter="F"};

            document.writeln("<h1> Your grade is " + letter "</h1>");
        </script>    
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: document.writeln("<h1> Your grade is " + letter "</h1>"); is missing a + between letter and the closing tag. i.e. document.writeln("<h1> Your grade is " + letter + "</h1>");

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `+` to concatenate the string

```
document.writeln("<h1> Your grade is " + letter "</h1>");
```

should be

```
document.writeln("<h1> Your grade is " + letter + "</h1>");
```

Other than that it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fqv9t/ (document.write replaced by alerts for fiddle)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added the + and I it worked, now I just need it to display the appropriate letter grade..can't get anything less than an A- I think my If statements are all messed up.